# IDE neutral project in versioning system

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, mercurial, project

I have a netbeans project that is under mercurial. What I would like to do is to strip down everything that makes this project netbeans project to only to leave code in there so that I can easily import it in say eclipse.

Is there some automated way to do this or do I have to remove manually this?

What approach would you recommend.

Cheers

Comment: Without netbeans, how are you going to compile the code and generate a war file? Do you have an ant file or other build instructions?

Comment: I will use an IDE but I dotn want to store IDE dependant files. What if I use Netbeans and someone else uses Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You only have to add the `nbproject` folder to ignore (= don't check in). All NetBean-settings are placed in this folder. Dont check in the `build` and `dist` folder as well, because these contain the compiled code (but they are ignored per default).

Comment: And the layout of the source folders is different. But it's a simple thing (in both Netbeans and Eclipse) to set the location of the source folder in the project.

Comment: Depends on how you setup your project etc.. But yes, its a simple thing.

Comment: Any place where I can find more about this conversion>?

Comment: You'll only have an `nbproject` folder in your NetBeans project if it is Ant-based. I've understood - see elsewhere - that the project in question is Maven-based.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do "IDE neutral projects" is to use Maven !

In NetBeans when the project is Maven-based (as opposed to Ant-based) you'll see that all those NetBeans-specific files that you normally see in `nbproject` folder are just not there. The `nbproject` folder doesn't even exist. The reason is that for a Maven-based project NetBeans essentially uses the `pom.xml` as the definition of the project and that's a good thing because the POM is portable and directly understood by other IDEs.

Even for a Maven-based project NetBeans will still store some IDE-specific stuff in a file called `nb-configuration.xml` but you can include all of the contents of this file as properties inside the `pom.xml`. These properties will then be ignored by other IDEs when they load the POM. This way you can pretty much avoid altogether to check any IDE-specific files into the VCS. Also it is worth mentioning that the stuff in `nb-configuration.xml` is never needed for someone else (using NetBeans or another IDE) to be able to *build* your project. Another way to put it is that it contains non-essential data. The POM - by virtue - is always guaranteed to be a complete description of how to build the project.

Contrary if your NetBeans project is Ant-based then at least in my experience you cannot avoid checking NetBeans specific files into the VCS ... because otherwise even those using NetBeans won't be able to correctly open your project.

However even with Maven there's one area where you'll be forced to have NetBeans-specific files in the VCS and that is if you use the Matisse GUI builder in NetBeans. The Matisse GUI builder produces some proprietary files with `.form` extension and you really need to have those in your VCS.  But this is the only example I can come up with where NetBeans-specific files will need to go into the VCS assuming your project is Maven-based.

If the project indeed *is* Maven-based and you still feel that there are NetBeans-specific files that you need to have in the VCS then let us know exactly which files you're thinking of. Then we can take it from there. :-)

Comment: I use maven, that is not the issue, the issue here is how to separate IDE dependant files when comming them to repository so that others can just pull src code and use what ever IDE they want. Right now they need to use Netbeans

Comment: Sounds strange that "they need to use NetBeans" if the project is Maven-based ?? Why?

Comment: Maven is not an IDE as far as I know :) so it has nothing to do with this. It is project and dependency management. I dont see how would this help when my question is how to keep source code clean of IDE related files when committing files into a repository

Comment: If the project is Maven-based then there should no need to commit any IDE-specific files into VCS. Take NetBeans's `nb-configuration.xml` file for example. You can copy copy/paste the contents of this file into the pom and then make sure the file itself is ignored by the VCS. These properties in the pom will then only make sense to a user who opens the project in NetBeans, all other IDEs will ignore them. The use of Maven is really what makes your project 'IDE neutral'.

Comment: Sorry, Boris, I'll make myself clear: If the project is Maven-based then you can open it in whatever IDE you like (Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ, etc) and it will work and you'll get the same result in all IDEs. And there will be no reason to commit any IDE specific files into VCS. This is Maven bringing you this benefit, not something else, hence my answer. In short: With Maven you can generally keep IDE specific files out of the VCS and I believe that was your question? Maven is the enabler of the 'IDE neutral' project. Don't understand the downvote. :-(

Comment: Project is already on maven, but I remember that I had trouble when trying to open it in eclpise - ie it didnt work :) I can try over the weekend again maybe it was problem with me :S